# Margin Issues in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser, margin

My website seems to be spaced nicely except in Chrome. There the nav bar is further down than the others and the background image has a little bit of extra space past the photo. See here

[Correct Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSn4a.jpg)

[Incorrect Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnOwD.jpg)

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>

  <head>
    <link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>


    <title>
      Lovers &amp; Fighters
    </title>
  </head>
  <body id="home">
      <header id="photo">
      </header>
      <footer>
      <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://chrismisterek.bandcamp.com" target="top">Music</a></li>
              <li>&#47;</li>
            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/loversandfighters1" target="top">Videos</a></li>
              <li>&#47;</li>
            <li><a href="http://facebook.com/loversandfighters">Social</a></li>
              <li>&#47;</li>
            <li><a href="mailto:chris.misterek@gmail.com" target="top">Email</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
#photo{
  position: relative;
  background: #BCBCBC;
  background-image: url(images/bandbanner1.4.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 109%;
  width: 101.8%;
  margin-top: -4%;
  margin-left: -1%;
  margin-bottom: -.7%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


nav{
  background-color: rgba(65,61,61,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  height: 10%;
  width: 104.5%;
  margin-left: -5%;
  margin-top: -4.6%;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul{
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 1.8%;
  margin-left: 28%;
  margin-bottom: -20%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 105%;
  font-family: 'Courier';
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li{
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

a:link{
  color: #BCBCBC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited{
  color: #BCBCBC;
}

a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: the bottom part of the 'right' image (I think you might have them mixed up in the question) looks a little like space for a scroll bar. MAYBE could you force the scroll bar to be ON but not available?

Comment: did you tried to apply a [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) for each browser ? i guess, it would be the solution because others browsers display your site correctly.

Comment: Try using px or em units instead and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you! I'd prefer to not use a pre made style sheet. More for exercise and learning. And, I initially tried everything in pixels and it was even worse than. It would only show correctly in Safari and nothing else. Not sure how to make the scroll unavailable? I tried hiding the overflow but then I had a white border around the entire website. I'd like the images to spill over a bit.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up putting the image in the html element and making the overflow hidden in that. It seemed to solve the problem. Something like this:

```
html {
  background: url(images/bandbanner1.4.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks all